# Superclass and subclass arguments

Tags: java, inheritance, polymorphism, overloading, overriding

I am providing two classes as follows:

Appliance class

```
public class Appliance {
    void start(Appliance t){
        System.out.println("Start Appliance");
    }
}
```

Toaster Class

```
public class Toaster extends Appliance {
    void start(Toaster t){
        System.out.println("Start Toaster");
    }
}
```

RunAppliance Class

```
public class RunAppliance {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Appliance appliance = new Toaster();
        Toaster toaster = new Toaster();
        appliance.start(toaster);
    }
}
```

Being a newbie,it confuses me between method overloading and overriding and also how arguments get impacted in one argument type is subclass of another argument type.Thus I am presenting 6 conditions for the same:

1)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Appliance* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Appliance* t)

2)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Toaster* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Toaster* t)

3)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Appliance* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Toaster* t)

4)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Toaster* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Appliance* t))

5)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Appliance* t) & void start(*Toaster* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Toaster* t)

6)**Appliance Class** : void start(*Appliance* t) ; **Toaster Class** : void start(*Appliance* t) & void start(*Toaster* t))

Can anybody suggest me a necessary rule for the same.

Comment: what exactly are you asking? what are those "6 conditions"?

Comment: What is a necessary rule ?

Comment: These are the different versions of same method having different argument type and bold ones are the class name in which they will be called in above code sections.

Comment: necessary rule means on what basis output can be predicted and how overloading and overriding takes place

Answer (score 1):

Your `Toaster` class is incorrect.  The argument for its `start()` method should be `Appliance`, not `Toaster`.

Your implementation fails the Liskov Substitution Principle.  You can't use a `Toaster` any place an `Appliance` is called for, because it doesn't override the `start()` method as written.

Do it this way:

```
public class Toaster extends Appliance {
    void start(Appliance a){
        System.out.println("Start Toaster");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your comment.so if i correct this error,how the behaviour will change on basis of conditions given and which are invalid.

Comment: I don't know how the behavior will change, but I do know what will happen: polymorphism means a runtime Appliance instance will print "Start Appliance" when you call its start() method; a runtime Toaster instance will print "Start Toaster" when you call its start() method.

Comment: Okz.so if i follow the principle only my first condition is right,all others are invalid??

Comment: I didn't read all that nonsense.  No parent class can know about subclasses.  All the situations that call for Appliance with a Toaster method are utterly wrong.

Comment: I did help you correct it.  I told you the correct answer and pointed out why the other five scenarios you dreamed up are wrong.  I'm not your buddy.  Accept the correct answer and move on.

Comment: Thanks a lot coder... :) actually i saw that half line of yours in which it was written "i didn't read all that nonsense", so asked for help and time.anyways it ok..

Comment: No loss.  No talent people like you come and go every day.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are asking what will be the output in each of the cases below:

```
    Appliance appliance = new Appliance();
    Appliance applianceToaster = new Toaster();
    Toaster toaster = new Toaster();
    appliance.start(appliance);
    appliance.start(toaster);
    appliance.start(applianceToaster);
    toaster.start(appliance);
    toaster.start(toaster);
    toaster.start(applianceToaster);
    applianceToaster.start(appliance);
    applianceToaster.start(toaster);
    applianceToaster.start(applianceToaster);
```

As @duffymo points out, change Toaster to Appliance in the Toaster start method. The start in Toaster will hide the start in Appliance for any object that is a Toaster at runtime. You would need to user super to access the start in Appliance from the start in Toaster.

At compile time appliance looks like Appliance, at runtime it is an Appliance, so the start in Appliance is called, regardless of which parameter is sent to it.

At compile time toaster looks like Toaster, at runtime it is a Toaster, so the start in Toaster is called, regardless of which parameter is sent to it.

At compile time applianceToaster looks like Appliance, at runtime it is a Toaster, so a polymorphic call is made to start in Toaster, regardless of the parameter sent to it.